# Can I use an enum as a struct name?

Tags: c++, c, enums

I think it may be called literal?

```
enum packet_structures{
   PacketOne,
   PacketTwo,
   PacketThree
};

struct PacketOne{
 unsigned int packet_id;
};
struct PacketTwo{
 unsigned int packet_id;
};

struct PacketThree{
 unsigned int packet_id;
};
```

And let's say I have a general packet.

```
struct PacketGeneral{
 packet_structures TypeOfPacket;
};

PacketGeneral newPacket;

newPacket.TypeOfPacket = PacketOne;
```

Can I literally use that enum's name to typecast a char* to a struct (i.e PacketOne)? Without having to typecast with (struct PacketOne), how can I just typecast that same struct but with just the enumeration newPacket.TypeOfPacket?

Comment: I think you'd need to write `struct PacketGeneral newPacket`. I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: What's the final goal of it? Do your want to do inheritance in "C"? if so why "C++" tag is here?

Comment: No, you can't. C has no reflection, and I doubt you actualy need any of this.

Comment: Just trying to find a way to typecast packets depending on what I msg_peek into the general (father) packet's enum type. So I could then read without msg_peek and read the correct sizeof struct then typecast that char* buffer into a struct PacketOne. It's doable but very ugly as in manually typecasting each and every struct. That's why I was hoping to use the Enum as an identifier for the structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. Enums are used for storing literals and not identifiers.

Comment: Is there anything else that we can use as an identifier? As in making a struct PacketOne without typing out "struct PacketOne myPacket"

Answer (score -1):

No, at least not in `C`.

`enum` declares/defines constant identifiers.

So, you cannot use those same identifier again as structure tag name.

You can check that by compiling a program containing these declarations/definitions.

Comment: Tags are in a separate name space from other identifiers, so the identifiers of an `enum` can be reused as structure tag names. (Of course, there will be no association between them.) You can check that by compiling a program containing these declarations, or by reading clause 6.2.3, paragraph 1 of the C 2011 standard (draft N1570).